# pgfplot polar errors

Tags: pgfplots, error-bars

I want to plot a dataset with pgfplot using the polaraxis with errors but i cant seem t oget it right:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}
\addplot+ [data cs=polarrad, only marks, error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,x dir=both,x explicit] table [x=x,x error=ex,y=y,y error=ey] {1INertTest.dat};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: the errorbars are all over the place]

```
x   y   ex  ey
1.63    18.64   0.10    0.2
1.62    16.44   0.10    0.2
1.59    14.15   0.10    0.2
1.56    11.88   0.10    0.2
1.51    9.62    0.10    0.2
1.43    7.39    0.10    0.2
1.28    5.26    0.10    0.2
1.00    3.29    0.10    0.2
0.24    2.11    0.10    0.2
-0.65   2.94    0.10    0.2
-1.01   4.77    0.10    0.2
-1.15   6.92    0.10    0.2
-1.24   9.08    0.10    0.2
-1.30   11.28   0.10    0.2
-1.34   13.51   0.10    0.2
-1.37   15.64   0.10    0.2
-1.40   17.87   0.10    0.2
```

Comment: As [Christian Feuersänger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1537/christian-feuers%c3%a4nger) (the author of PGFPlots) told me, currently there is no implementation for error bars in polar axis. If you wish to change that, please file a feature request in the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/). Maybe there will be an implementation eventually ;)